# What is she saying?

Tags: translation

http://picosong.com/VamJ

Can anyone understand the first part of what she's saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is saying 「[足]{あし}さえ[止]{と}めなければ、きっと[追]{お}いつけるわよ。」.

Sandwiched between "sh" and "s", which are somewhat similar, the 「い」 vowel in 「し」 of 「[足]{あし}さえ」 was not pronounced clearly.  I think that is what prevented you from catching the first couple of words.

Comment: thanks a lot. I've been listening to this for 10 minutes and didn't come up with anything other than assa :)